# UINavigation: Rules on how to present Viewcontroller (push/replace)

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

When you take a look at apple's own apps (like `settings`-App) you will find that most of the `UIViewControllers` are presented inside a `UINavigationController` and presented by pushing it thus allowing the user to easily move back using the back-button.
However some `UIViewControllers` are presented modally (still with a `UINavigationBar`) but instead of a back-button they have a-cancel button.

I wonder is there a "rule" or are there "guidelines" like when to use which type of presentation style?

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775643/why-present-modal-view-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such a rule, there are [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/). It depends on what functionality you want to provide. Pushing and presenting are two different approaches to achieve the same goal, show controlled view to the user. Depending on the case, you can present or push view controller. It's up to you to decide what would be more comfortable to your users.